# Sharepoint dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-2007

In a list i have a status columns. In edit form, on change of status to not approved  i want to show the comment text box. I want to  do using designer or javascript. Pl Help.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly use A custom aspx page with HTML controls and use the javascript API from following link to update to the sharepoint 
[Office Live JavaScript API](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/22/examples-for-the-sharepoint-and-office-live-javascript-api/)

Comment: SharePoint Farm Controls are run at server in nature so you can not attach a javascript function the other way round is to find the control for status column and dyanamically attach a even to it on page load example for the same is provided below

element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);
another_element.addEventListener('click',doSomething,false);

function doSomething() { this.style.backgroundColor = '#cc0000'; }